# Change matplotlib offset notation from scientific to plain

Tags: python, matplotlib, offset, scientific-notation

I want to set the formatting of the y-axis offset in my plot to non-scientific notation, but I can't find a setting to do this. Other questions and their solutions describe how to either remove the offset altogether, or set the y-ticks to scientific/plain notation; I haven't found an answer for setting the **notation of the offset** itself.

I've already tried using these two options, but I think they're meant for the y-ticks, not the offsets:

```
ax.ticklabel_format(axis='y', style='plain', useOffset=6378.1)
```

and

```
ax.get_yaxis().get_major_formatter().set_scientific(False)
```

So, the actual result is `+6.3781e3`, when I want `+6378.1`

Any way to do this?

Edit: Added example code and figure:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import ticker
plt.rcParams['font.family'] = 'monospace'
import random

Date = range(10)
R = [6373.1+10*random.random() for i in range(10)]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(9,6))
ax.plot(Date,R,'-D',zorder=2,markersize=3)
ax.ticklabel_format(axis='y', style='plain', useOffset=6378.1)
ax.set_ylabel('Mean R (km)',fontsize='small',labelpad=1)

plt.show()
```

[image: Example image with data centered around the offset I want]

Comment: Please add a Minimal Working Example that reproduces your problem.

Comment: @b-fg Added working code and figure

Comment: Good. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A way to do this is to disable the offset text itself and add your custom `ax.text` there as follows

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import random

plt.rcParams['font.family'] = 'monospace'

offset = 6378.1

Date = range(10)
R = [offset+10*random.random() for i in range(10)]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(9,6))
ax.plot(Date,R,'-D',zorder=2,markersize=3)
ax.ticklabel_format(axis='y', style='plain', useOffset=offset)
ax.set_ylabel('Mean R (km)',fontsize='small',labelpad=1)

ax.yaxis.offsetText.set_visible(False)
ax.text(x = 0.0, y = 1.01, s = str(offset), transform=ax.transAxes)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can subclass the default `ScalarFormatter` and replace the `get_offset` method, such that it would simply return the offset as it is. Note that if you wanted to make this compatible with the multiplicative "offset", this solution would need to be adapted (currently it just prints a warning).

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker
import random

class PlainOffsetScalarFormatter(matplotlib.ticker.ScalarFormatter):
    def get_offset(self):
        if len(self.locs) == 0:
            return ''
        if self.orderOfMagnitude:
            print("Your plot will likely be labelled incorrectly")
        return self.offset

Date = range(10)
R = [6373.1+10*random.random() for i in range(10)]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(9,6))
ax.plot(Date,R,'-D',zorder=2,markersize=3)

ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(PlainOffsetScalarFormatter())
ax.ticklabel_format(axis='y', style='plain', useOffset=6378.1)
ax.set_ylabel('Mean R (km)',fontsize='small',labelpad=1)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Subclassing the ScalarFormatter does indeed seem elegant.
I just found the + to be missing on the offset.
This can be fixed by adding a conditional statement that transforms it into a string and inserts an +  at the beginning if the offset is positive