# How to prevent 1e9 from being shown to exponential form in Python matplotlib figure

Tags: matplotlib

I've seen this. [How to prevent numbers being changed to exponential form in Python matplotlib figure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14711655/how-to-prevent-numbers-being-changed-to-exponential-form-in-python-matplotlib-fi)

However, I've got some custom annotations to put in, and I'd just like `matplotlib` to just not show the 1e9 marker. Example code below

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
sns.set()  # not necessary, but just to reproduce the photo below

f, a = plt.subplots()  # I use the oop interface
pd.DataFrame({'y': [1e9, 2e9, 3e9], 'x': [1, 2, 3]}).set_index('x').plot(ax=a)
```

Yields:

[image]

How do I just not show the `1e9`? I have a custom annotation there which says 'billions' and it overlaps.

Comment: Something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53878397/change-matplotlib-offset-notation-from-scientific-to-plain/53883385#53883385

Comment: Or maybe this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45760763/how-to-move-the-y-axis-scale-factor-to-the-position-next-to-the-y-axis-label

Comment: `pd.DataFrame({'y': [1e9, 2e9, 3e9], 'x': [1, 2, 3]}).set_index('x').div(1e9).plot(ax=a)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My thanks to ImportanceOfBeingErnest above, as

```
a.yaxis.offsetText.set_visible(False)
```

solves.